# Initialise covariance structure in lme

Tags: r, mixed-models

How can I initialise a unstructured covariance matrix for the following model?

```
y<-data.frame(response=c(10,19,27,28,9,13,25,29,4,10,20,18,5,6,12,17),
               treatment=factor(rep(1:4,4)),
               subject=factor(rep(1:4,each=4))
               )
fit<-lme(response~-1+treatment,y,random=~1|subject,
         correlation=corSymm(form=~1|subject))
```

I tried some variants but I get every time I get the error:

```
Error in lme.formula(response ~ -1 + treatment, y, random = ~1 |  : 
  nlminb problem, convergence error code = 1
  message = function evaluation limit reached without convergence (9)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's practically difficult to fit an unstructured correlation matrix with 6 parameters in addition to a treatment mean effect (4 parameters), a random-effects variance (1), and a residual variance (1) to a data set with only 16 points.  If I try with a larger, randomized version of your data set, it works fine.

```
nSubj <- 20
respVec <- c(10,19,27,28,9,13,25,29,4,10,20,18,5,6,12,17)
set.seed(101)
y<-data.frame(response=sample(respVec,size=4*nSubj,replace=TRUE),
               treatment=factor(rep(1:4,nSubj)),
               subject=factor(rep(1:nSubj,each=4))
               )
library(nlme)
fit<-lme(response~-1+treatment,y,random=~1|subject,
         correlation=corSymm(form=~1|subject),
         control=lmeControl(msVerbose=TRUE))
```

Now we can experiment and see how small a data set we can get away with. Package the stuff above into a test function that simulates data and tries a fit, returning `TRUE` if the fit fails:

```
testFun <- function(nSubj) {
    y<-data.frame(response=sample(respVec,size=4*nSubj,replace=TRUE),
               treatment=factor(rep(1:4,nSubj)),
               subject=factor(rep(1:nSubj,each=4))
               )
    fit <- try(lme(response~-1+treatment,y,random=~1|subject,
         correlation=corSymm(form=~1|subject)),silent=TRUE)
    inherits(fit,"try-error")
}
```

Try the test function `N` times and report the proportion of failures:

```
testFun2 <- function(nSubj,N) {
   mean(replicate(N,testFun(nSubj)))
}
```

Try it out for a range of numbers of subjects (slow):

```
set.seed(101)
testRes <- sapply(4:20,testFun2,N=50)
```

Results:

```
##  [1] 0.64 0.04 0.00 0.00  ... 0.00
```

Somewhat to my surprise, this will work a third of the time with 4 subjects; 96% of the time with 5 subjects: and always with >5 subjects.

Comment: okay so it depends on number of subjects. Is it more meaning full if I would resample the data in the following way? `respVec <- matrix(c(10,19,27,28,9,13,25,29,4,10,20,18,5,6,12,17),4*nSubj,4,byrow=T)
set.seed(101)
idx<-sample(1:4,nSubj,replace=T)
y<-data.frame(response=c(t(respVec[idx,])),
               treatment=factor(rep(1:4,nSubj)),
               subject=factor(rep(1:nSubj,each=4))
               )`

Comment: Just to be clear, I wasn't proposing that you could *actually* estimate the parameters from this set of data this way.  I was suggesting that you simply don't have enough data to fit this model reliably.  The sampling procedure I did above was just a way to simulate whether it would be feasible to estimate the full model *if* you had enough data.